# How to randomize mouse clicking in Selenium (never the same element)?

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to randomize clicking on windows 10 python 3. The code below works except it’s not clicking the elements randomly. It also clicks at a ridiculously fast rate. To try and stop this I added time.sleep(3) but this tends to make it fail and gives an error which is not present without this sleep command. All elements appear to be already loaded.  See for error message with sleep: https://ibb.co/cUYL45

```
       import time
        from selenium import webdriver
        from random import randint

        driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r'C:\Brother\chromedriver.exe')
        driver.set_window_size(1024, 600)
        driver.maximize_window()

        time.sleep( 4 )

        driver.get('https://www.unibet.com.au/betting#drill-down/football')


        time.sleep( 10 )
        links = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector('.KambiBC-drill-down-navigation__toggle')
    #Not randomising??
        l = links[randint(0, len(links)-1)]
        for l in links:
            l.click()
#Tends to give error when I have a sleep command but it's goes way to fast not to have it. 
 #All elements have already loaded so explicit not needed..
            time.sleep(5)
            ...


        time.sleep( 5 )



        driver.close()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to click on random element (element from list with random index) you can try

```
l = links[randint(0, len(links)-1)]
l.click()
```

instead of

```
l = links[randint(0, len(links)-1)]
for l in links:
    l.click()
```

Note that `l` in `l = links[randint(0, len(links)-1)]` and `l` in `for l in links` are different variables

If you want to click each time new `option` element from drop-down, you can try below:

```
from random import shuffle
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait as wait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium import webdriver as web

driver = web.Chrome()
driver.get('https://ubet.com/sports/soccer')

options = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//select[./option="Soccer"]/option')

# Get list of inetegers [1, 2, ... n]
indexes = [index for index in range(len(options))]
# Shuffle them
shuffle(indexes)
for index in indexes:
    # Click on random option
    wait(driver, 10).until(
        EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '(//select[./option="Soccer"]/option)[%s]' % str(index + 1)))).click()
```

Comment: It only clicks about 3 elements before it finishes looping and moves on to next part of script.  It doesn't seem to be looping

Comment: Can you clarify how exactly you want to click those elements? Do you want to make `n` clicks on random elements where `n = len(links)`?

Comment: I'm wanting to click all of .KambiBC-drill-down-navigation__toggle elements (37 elements+ varies day to day) in a random order.  So ideally the same element isn't clicked twice.  Does this clarify  sort of?

Comment: Oh.. I see. I remember that in previous ticket you ask about `shuffle(list)`... It doesn't work as expected? What was the problem with that solution? Maybe it requires some improvement

Comment: Na that works great, it's just some pages you can't always rely on HREF.  I can give you an example page to show you what I mean if you want.  https://ubet.com/sports/soccer/australia-a-league <-- Theres a dropdown list on this webpage and the css is: .grouped > optgroup:nth-child(1) > option:nth-child(1).  So randomising that with driver is impossible

Comment: So your step sequence is to 1. Click drop-down. 2. Click option that wasn't clicked yet. And do this in a loop until all options clicked, right?

Comment: I tried using the above code in my question and it clicked all of the .grouped -> optgroup > option but too quickly and then got errors with wait time. I just used driver.find_elements_by_css_selector(".grouped > optgroup > option")

Comment: It works but is there a way to slow it down a little.   time.sleep(4) seems to continue to give me errors.  It also fails sometimes before its done launched to webpage (slow internet sometimes)

Comment: If you already defined `wait` as `WebDriver(driver, 10)`, then call it as `wait.until(EC.element_` instead of `wait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_`

Comment: I still get error for some reason.    https://ibb.co/k4apxQ - with CSS Wait
https://ibb.co/cTBFMk - Time.Sleep
...Expected type str, got int -> 1 [Highlighted green xpath]
Pep 8: line too long (156 > 120 char) [Number 1]

Comment: Oh, yep, sorry... `'//*[contains(@class, "KambiBC-drill-down-navigation__toggle")][%s]' % str(index + 1)`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/153040/discussion-between-andersson-and-hayden-darcy).